# provides free job training programs

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, style, redundancy

I'm wondering if it is advisable to remove the "programs" in the following. If so, why?

> This institute provides free job training **programs** for adults.

Comment: The advisability depends on the context. That sentence is good English both the way it is, and without "programs".

Answer (score 1):

With "programs" the sentence suggests structure to me - perhaps the organization offers regularly scheduled classes with training for particular jobs.

Without "programs" the promise is less focused. Without "for adults" it might even refer to on the job training.

Which way to write the sentence depends on what you want your readers to understand.

Comment: If "programs" is used, is it advisable to use a different verb, say, "run"?

Comment: "Run" might suggest that someone else has designed the programs and you are providing facilities. Stick with "provides" or "offers". But we can't really advise you without a lot more context.